# Azure storage account is not mounted but says it is

Tags: windows, azure, azure-storage, azure-app-service-envrmnt, mount-point

I mounted an Azure storage account to an Azure app service using this guide: https://azure.github.io/AppService/2018/09/24/Announcing-Bring-your-own-Storage-to-App-Service.html

When I use the console command it adds a configuration and all seems to be ok. It even says `"state":"ok"`, but when I take a look into my app service it seems the mount does not exist.

[image]

I uploaded a file into the file share container:

[image]

But I don't see it at the mount location:

[image]

I tried to use different file paths for the mount. Like `D:\home\test` etc. It all doesn't seem to work. BTW, I'm using a windows type app service.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Be careful to share your Storage Access Key it gives full rights on your storage to anyone who has the key, it seems mounting does not work for Windows Web App, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33545250/how-can-i-use-azure-file-storage-with-web-app-service

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use "Azure File Storage" with Web App Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33545250/how-can-i-use-azure-file-storage-with-web-app-service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ivan Ignatiev is correct. Currently azure files mount only supports for `Windows Containers Web Apps` and `App Service on Linux`, you can follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage) for steps. Or you can do it via azure portal UI like below:

[image]

And for the web app not on linux or windows container, you should use [azure file rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/file-service-rest-api) or [sdk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files) respectively.

Comment: Indeed you are right, I did not see that it said *windows* ***container***. It is kind of difficult for newcomers to see the difference. So to add up to your answer there are a few flavors of app service. First you can choose between publish method and then between windows and linux. So there are *windows, linux, windows container, linux container*. The containers are based on docker and offer you to use your own customised environment. If you don't need fancy customisation you can use a predefined environment. Only the predefined windows environment does not support file mount.