# Use mounted Azure Blob Storage Container in Azure App Service

Tags: django, azure, mount, azure-blob-storage, azure-appservice

I was able to mount azure blob storage on my local machine (Ubuntu 18.04) using blobfuse, just as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure//storage/blobs/storage-how-to-mount-container-linux).

To use it in an Azure App Service I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54460832/13183775), describing an option to mount Azure Storage using the Azure Portal interface. This does it for me...

But how can I access the mounted storage from within my Django app?

Is the mounted Storage accessible as directory via the filesystem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is pretty obvious and now also well documented.

When [mounting the Storage](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/blob/master/BringYourOwnStorage/mounting_azure_blob.md) you have the option to specify the mount path.